# Second derivative of a metric in terms of the Riemann curvature tensor.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I can't see how to get the following result. Help would be appreciated!

This question has to do with the [Riemann curvature tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor) in inertial coordinates.

Such that, if I'm not wrong, (in inertial coordinates) $$R_{abcd}=\frac{1}{2} (g_{ad,bc}+g_{bc,ad}-g_{bd,ac}-g_{ac,bd})$$
where $",_i"$ denotes $\partial \over \partial x^i$.

How does $$g_{ab,cd}=-\frac{1}{3}(R_{acbd}+R_{adbc})$$?

---

So
$$-\frac{1}{3}(R_{acbd}+R_{adbc})=-\frac{1}{6}(g_{bc,ad}+g_{ad,bc}-g_{ba,cd}-g_{cd,ab}+g_{bd,ac}+g_{ac,bd}-g_{ab,cd}-g_{cd,ab})$$
$$=-\frac{1}{6}(g_{bc,ad}+g_{ad,bc}+g_{bd,ac}+g_{ac,bd})+\frac{1}{3}g_{cd,ab}+\frac{1}{3}g_{ab,cd}$$
But how does $$\frac{1}{6}(g_{bc,ad}+g_{ad,bc}+g_{bd,ac}+g_{ac,bd})+\frac{1}{3}g_{cd,ab}=\frac{2}{3}g_{ab,cd}$$

---

...Have I made a mistake?

---

Somebody please? :(

Comment: Sorry, no time to write an answer at the moment, but you can look at [this](http://users.monash.edu.au/~leo/research/papers/files/lcb96-01.pdf) paper for a hint on p.3, or read the whole very detailed story [here](http://www.rose-hulman.edu/mathjournal/archives/2002/vol3-n2/Wolfe/Rmn_Metric.pdf).

Comment: If it helped, and you realized what was the problem, please consider adding your own answer :-)

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980226/getting-ricci-curvature-from-g-ab-cd